# What is the ssh password of hashicorp packer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sudo, hashicorp-packer

Once you created an image using packer. How do you get the root/ packer/ (any user with sudo privilege)'s password?

packer.json

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "googlecompute",
      "project_id": "project-id",
      "source_image": "ubuntu-2004-focal-v20220615",
      "ssh_username": "packer",
      "zone": "us-west1-a"
    }
  ],
}
```

After running:

```
packer build packer.json #a Ubuntu image is created.
```

Next step, how do I create a sudo user's account?

Comment: 1) Google Cloud Compute Images have password-based logins disabled. You would need to modify the OpenSSH server configuration to enable passwords. Setup SSH keys instead. 2) To create users, declare a **provisioner** of type **shell** and run normal Linux commands. Edit your question to show your entire **packer.json**.

Comment: Thank you John. 

So, (1) I need to edit **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** to enable password authentication in ssh; Also, (2) I should create the sudo user I want in the provisioning script of packer. Is this understanding correct?

Second, this is already my entire packer.json. I did not provision anything because I just was just trying to create image through packer.

Comment: Do not enable passwords, use SSH keys. Yes, you will need to create a user and enable that user as a member of the sudo group and specify the SSH public key for authentication.